# Python -- Regex -- How to find a string between two sets of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, tags

Consider the following:

```
<div id=hotlinklist>
  <a href="foo1.com">Foo1</a>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/extract">Extract</a>
  </div>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would you go about taking out the sitemap line with regex in **python**?

```
<a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
```

The following can be used to pull out the anchor tags.

```
'/<a(.*?)a>/i'
```

However, there are multiple anchor tags. Also there are multiple hotlink(s) so we can't really use them either?

Comment: You will probably hear that regular expressions are not suitable for parsing a context-free language like HTML.

Comment: If you're the one generating that HTML, it's worth noting that multiple, identical `id=` attributes like that are not valid.  A `class=` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use a regex. Use [BeautfulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), an HTML parser.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = \
"""
<div id=hotlinklist>
  <a href="foo1.com">Foo1</a>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/extract">Extract</a>
  </div>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
  </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.findAll("div",id="hotlink")[2].a

# <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Parsing HTML with regular expression is a bad idea!

Think about the following piece of html

```
<a></a > <!-- legal html, but won't pass your regex -->

<a href="/sitemap">Sitemap<!-- proof that a>b iff ab>1 --></a>
```

There are many more such examples. Regular expressions are good for many things, but not for parsing HTML.

You should consider using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) python HTML parser.

Anyhow, a ad-hoc solution using regex is

```
import re

data = """
<div id=hotlinklist>
  <a href="foo1.com">Foo1</a>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/extract">Extract</a>
  </div>
  <div id=hotlink>
    <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
  </div>
</div>
"""

e = re.compile('<a *[^>]*>.*</a *>')

print e.findall(data)
```

Output:

```
>>> e.findall(data)
['<a href="foo1.com">Foo1</a>', '<a href="/">Home</a>', '<a href="/extract">Extract</a>', '<a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>']
```

Comment: If you replace that `.*` with `(?:[^<]+|<(!/a\b))*`, you'll get fewer false positives, without blowing up the regex engine with backtracking.

Answer (score 5):

In order to extract the contents of the tagline:

```
    <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
```

... I would use:

```
    >>> import re
    >>> s = '''
    <div id=hotlinklist>
    <a href="foo1.com">Foo1</a>
      <div id=hotlink>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div id=hotlink>
        <a href="/extract">Extract</a>
      </div>
      <div id=hotlink>
        <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
      </div>
    </div>'''
    >>> m = re.compile(r'<a href="/sitemap">(.*?)</a>').search(s)
    >>> m.group(1)
    'Sitemap'
```

Comment: Actually, replace sitemap with XYZ as it really can be anything.
I would only know that it is the 3rd div within the hotlinlist div.


The html pattern that used can be repeated many times. 
Let say I want to take out all the smart phones listing on ebay.

I would know that the above pattern is repeated for each smart phone found, however, the <a herf="XYZ">XYZ</a> can be an iphone, blackberry, Nokia or any other smart phone. There could be no item or 100s.

So, I was looking for something that says find the repeated pattern, then take the smart phone line out and have a list of smart phones.

Comment: I like this as it answers the question. It also helped me with understanding regex better believe it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://www.codespeak.net/lxml/) if you need to parse HTML.

Also, what is it that you really need to do? Find the last link? Find the third link? Find the link that points to /sitemap? It's unclear from you question. What do you need to *do* with the data?

If you really have to use regular expressions, have a look at `findall`.