# How can I match the price in this string by python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

How can I match the price in this string?

```
    <div id="price_amount" itemprop="price" class="h1 text-special">
      $58
    </div>
```

I want the $58 in this string, how to do that? This is what I am tring, but doesn't work:

```
    regex = r'<div id="price_amount" itemprop="price" class="h1 text-special">(.+?)</div>'
    price = re.findall(regex, string)
```

Comment: Refer to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849912/python-regex-how-to-find-a-string-between-two-sets-of-strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not use `regex` for this particular problem. Look into an XML/HTML parsing library for Python instead.

Having said that, your regex is just missing a match for the newlines, so you need to add `\s*` after the opening tag and before the closing tag.

```
import re

string="""
    <div id="price_amount" itemprop="price" class="h1 text-special">
      $58
    </div>
    """
regex = r'<div id="price_amount" itemprop="price" class="h1 text-special">\s*(.+?)\s*</div>'
price = re.findall(regex, string)
print price
```

Comment: You might want to use the non-greedy versions

Comment: @thefourtheye, Actually, then you would match a whole bunch of extra whiteespace inside the capture, which I assume the OP doesn't want.

Comment: The reason to use XML/HTML parsing, is it more accurate and fast?

Comment: @liaozd, It is faster, more reliable, and generally not as much of a headache. Regular expressions were not designed to parse XML.

Comment: @liaozd, [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is some entertaining and also good reference material on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Try to capture only the price which was inbetween `<div></div>` tags,

```
import re
str=('<div id="price_amount" itemprop="price" class="h1 text-special">'
     '$58'
     '</div>')
regex = r'<div id="price_amount" itemprop="price" class="h1 text-special">([^<]*?)</div>'
price= re.search(regex, str)
price.group(1) # => '$58'
```

`([^<]*?)` this code will catch any character not of `<` zero or more times and stores the captured character into a group(`group1`).`?` followed by `*` means a non-greedy match.